# Extra large icons in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu, right-click

in Windows 7, we know that in right click option "View" we have some options, one of the is "Extra large icons".

Is it possible to

1. to view icons larger when we choose "Extra large icons"
2. or add one more option to this second menu that work as extra Extra large icons.

My goal is to preview first page of PDF files without opening each one.

Comment: Directory Opus has the capability to display thumbnail or icon previews up to 4096 x 4096 pixels.

Comment: Extra Large Icons is the largest icon size available by default. Tweaking other settings such as scaling and resolution can make all elements on your screen larger. But this means your question doesn't make sense. What are you trying to accomplish? Are you dealing with a vision issue? There is special software designed for extreme magnification for assisting with vision issues when the default Windows accessibility options are not enough.

Answer (score 1):

To increase/decrease the icon/thumbnail preview in Windows Explorer, use the mouse
scroll-wheel.

When the folder is displayed in Explorer, right-click an empty space inside it,
then select *View > Large icons*. Next, press and hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
key and at the same time scroll the mouse wheel up/down to increase/decrease
the preview icon size.

This will also work on the desktop icons.

If you want to use this exact same layout for all folders, then click Explorer's
*File* menu, then go to "Change folder and search options".
The "Folder Options" window will appear; click the "View" tab.
Under the "Folder views" heading, click the "Apply to folders" button and
to make all your folders open up the same size.

Comment: thanks, but the method you suggested using ctrl+mouse wheel has a maximum size as View->Extra large icons, but I needed somehow larger that I can see first page preview of PDF files.

Comment: The only larger view I know of is the [Preview Pane](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/61510-preview-pane-turn-off.html).